# How I can get SRC value from string?

Tags: php

How I can get SRC value from string using regular expression: **src="value"**?

**I tried:**

```
 preg_match(src="(.+?)", $subject, $matches);
```

Comment: Not duplicated, I need get SRC from string, here from HTML

Comment: `/src=(["'])(.*?)\1/` read all the answers

Comment: Nope, you are right: /src="(.*?)"/i

Comment: I get result array: `array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(107) "src="http://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2014/11/17/13/20141117135142299/hear_0ea5b83087351bd2c8b3e6390bf1d5ec.jpg""
  [1]=>
  string(1) """
  [2]=>
  string(101) "http://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2014/11/17/13/20141117135142299/hear_0ea5b83087351bd2c8b3e6390bf1d5ec.jpg"
}` Why I get  `[1]=>
  string(1) """`